# Avoid repetitive typescript definitions

Tags: typescript

Say I have these TS definitions:

```
export type SearchStackParamList = {
  SearchScreen: undefined;
  Restaurant: undefined;
};

export type SearchScreenProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList, 'SearchScreen'>,
  CompositeScreenProps<
    NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >
>;

export type RestaurantScreenProps = CompositeScreenProps<
  NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList, 'Restaurant'>,
  CompositeScreenProps<
    NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >
>;
```

See how `SearchScreenProps` and `RestaurantScreenProps` are kinda redundant? Is there a way I can improve this so it's less verbose? Maybe through some kind of "extend" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper type that takes a string type as a generic and gives the big complicated `CompositeScreenProps` in exchange.

```
type ScreenProps<T extends string> = CompositeScreenProps<
  NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList, T>,
  CompositeScreenProps<
    NativeStackScreenProps<SearchStackParamList>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >
>;

export type SearchScreenProps = ScreenProps<'SearchScreen'>;
export type RestaurantScreenProps = ScreenProps<'Restaurant'>;
```

If `extends string` is too broad, you can use `'SearchScreen' | 'Restaurant'` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: Just one thing, I get a TS warning for "T": `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof SearchStackParamList'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof SearchStackParamList'.` So just replacing string with keyof SearchStackParamList is probably necessary?

Comment: *If `extends string` is too broad, you can use `'SearchScreen' | 'Restaurant'` or whatever is appropriate.* - so use `T extends keyof SearchStackParamList` instead